# Return Value Based on Three Variables

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm creating a table where a user selects three variables from drop down lists (data validation lists). These three variables determine the price per square foot of a product. I would like to make it so the price is automatically returned once all selections have been made. I have a table that determines the price that should be returned but no idea on how to put everything together in the correct way. I understand this isn't a macro writing service (i'm assuming that's the way I'll have to go), but I would appreciate any hints or ideas as to the best way to go about getting what I need. If a more detailed description is needed of all possible variables I can provide that.

[image: Example of Current Setup]

EDIT

Here is the table:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rliQ5.png)

I apologize, I have not yet been able to import into Excel. But this should give an idea of the amount of variables involved. I plan on having the table located in a different sheet.

EDIT 2

By the way, I'm using Excel 2016.

Comment: This can be done with an array type formula. But without knowing where the lookup table is it hard to answer.

Comment: show an example and the price table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have data like:

[image]

Enter the type in **E1**, the size in **F1** and the age in **G1**.  Then in **H1** enter:

```
=INDEX(D1:D18,SUMPRODUCT((A1:A18=E1)*(B1:B18=F1)*(C1:C18=G1)*ROW(1:18)))
```

[image]

Comment: It appears that this only works when the reference table is on the same sheet. When I try to link to another sheet I get a #REF! error. Is there a way to make it so that the reference table can be on a different sheet? This works great if the data is on the same page, though, so thanks for the help!

Comment: I personally would go with a SUMIFS() in this instance as the combinations are unique and avoid the array formula.  `=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,E1,B:B,F1,C:C,G1)` But I do like the use of SUMPRODUCT to avoid the CSE.